# How to obtain the linear terms of the expansion?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion

Consider the following function, which is actually linear on the going-to-expand points. I want to use Mathematica to expand the function near these points, and keep only the linear terms, i.e. the results should looks as: $a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)$:

```
f[x_, y_] := Sqrt[3 + 2 Cos[Sqrt[3] y] + 4 Cos[Sqrt[3]/2 y] Cos[3/2 x]]
d = 4 Pi/(3 Sqrt[3]);
Plot[{f[x, d], -f[x, d]}, {x, -0.01, 0.01}](*Plot around r1*)
Plot[{f[0, d + y], -f[0, d + y]}, {y, -0.01, 0.01}]
(*Expand around these three Points, keep only linear term*)
r1 = {0, d};
r2 = {Sqrt[3]/2 d, -1/2 d};
r3 = {-Sqrt[3]/2 d, -1/2 d};
```

I have tried using `Series`, but I got no terms linear on x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can get such approximation across a cuspid, hence you have to consider only one side of it, for instance

```
s1[x_,y_] = Assuming[x > 0 && y > d,
  Series[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, d, 1}]
] // Normal

s1[x,y]//N
```

> 1.5 (-2.4184 + y)

```
Plot3D[{s1[x, y], f[x, y]}, {x, -.01, .01}, {y, d - .01, d + .01}
       , AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a helper function:

```
s[x0_, y0_] := Normal@Series[Series[f[x, y], {x, x0, 1}], {y, y0, 1}]
```

Now we can compute series expansions:

```
Limit[s[x0, y0], Thread[{x0, y0} -> r1], Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

> `-(1/8) x (-12 + 4 Sqrt[3] π - 9 y)`

```
Limit[s[x0, y0], Thread[{x0, y0} -> r1], Direction -> "FromBelow"]
```

> `1/8 x (-12 + 4 Sqrt[3] π - 9 y)`

```
Limit[s[x0, y0], Thread[{x0, y0} -> r2], Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

> `-(1/24) (2 π - 3 x) (12 + 2 Sqrt[3] π + 9 y)`

```
Limit[s[x0, y0], Thread[{x0, y0} -> r2], Direction -> "FromBelow"]
```

> `1/24 (2 π - 3 x) (12 + 2 Sqrt[3] π + 9 y)`

```
Limit[s[x0, y0], Thread[{x0, y0} -> r3], Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

> `1/24 (2 π + 3 x) (12 + 2 Sqrt[3] π + 9 y)`

```
Limit[s[x0, y0], Thread[{x0, y0} -> r3], Direction -> "FromBelow"]
```

> `-(1/24) (2 π + 3 x) (12 + 2 Sqrt[3] π + 9 y)`

You see the limits are different, so there is no sereies expansion at given points.